# MySQL Database Activity Monitoring Solutions

Tags: mysql

We are looking for a DAM solution for MySQL.

There is of course GreenSQL but it seems to lack some of the features we desire like robust filtering of reports for export purposes, etc. It's very basic.

Gartner lists off a bunch of Technology Providers in their article "Database Activity Monitoring is Evolving into Database Audit and Protection" but of the 7 vendors listed (Application Security, BeyondTrust, IBM, Imperva, McAfee, Oracle, WareValley) only 3 of them actually support MySQL. Those vendors are: Imperva, McAfee & WareValley.

Imperva looks full-featured but is wildly expensive. It requires a separate Management Server install.

McAfee has a free plugin for MySQL but from what I can tell it writes out a log on the operational DB Server(s) and then you need to have a separate install on a Windows Server of ePolicy Orchestrator to do anything useful.

WareValley is a Korean company that seems to have virtually no presence in North America. We've got feelers out to the one-and-only NA Partner but I don't have much confidence in terms of support.

Generally it seems like there is no mid-market in this space.

Are there other DAM solutions for MySQL that you know about?

Thanks!